# php write append a file, repeats unwanted

Tags: php, html

I have the following script which I call from a form (action) to fetch the given data in the form.  But when I tried to write this form data into a file. It seems to repeat itself and I can't find out what's wrong in the code.

In this example, I cleaned "testfile.txt". So it has a fresh start. In the HTML form, I entered the postcode which is 1212 aa
however as a 'bonus' I get about 15 times a line with postcode.

```
<?php

    $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt =  "postcode" . $_POST['entry_508642568'];
    echo $txt;
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

?>
```

output:

```
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode
postcode1212 aa
postcode
postcode
postcode
```

Comment: The PHP code looks good. Could you post the html of the form you're using?

Comment: Try to replace the `"a"` with `"w"` and check if what happens.

Comment: It's very likely that the script you posted gets executed multiple times with an empty `$_POST`  and once with a populated `$_POST`

Comment: `$txt =  "postcode" . $_POST['entry_508642568'];` this will always write one value not all value , because i think it's one index of `POST` array containing one `value`

Comment: try checking by changing the string postcode. then locate the file and see if there's a change.

Comment: @Vishwa  good idea, I was focused on the PHP, Checking the HTML and JS now

Comment: @Claudios it just write one time, but it's not the solution.

Comment: @dimlucas. I think you are write, but what triggers it that it write it so many times.

Comment: @Anat I don't complete understand what you mean, But the $_POST contains the whole adress. I just gave the relevant snippet

Comment: @Richard  Even if you do something with HTML to fix it, it is a good idea to check inside your PHP code as well. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like somehow the form is getting submitted multiple times. Either fix that or try checking for input first before you append to file.

```
<?php

    if( !empty($_POST['entry_508642568']) ) {

        $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt =  "postcode" . $_POST['entry_508642568'];
        echo $txt;
        fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }

?>
```

Comment: It must be some JS what refresh some info on the page, but still don't get how. However, this solution solve the problem too. Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

The answer above was good but you can also use flags to handle Write a string to a file.

```
<?php

    if( !empty($_POST['entry_508642568']) ) {

        $file = 'testfile.txt';
        $txt =  "postcode" . $_POST['entry_508642568'];
        file_put_contents($file, $txt, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        //LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
    }

?>
```